# Building a toggle with a flipflop?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I'm trying to build a toggle that turns a 4 bit counter on or off. Here's where I'm at so far:

[image: Switch]

As you can see, I'm using a single D flip flop. Ideally I want one switch to disable the chip, and another to re-enable it.

Im lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the clocked output from the switch as the clock to a control flop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDZTTZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A human pressing a button should be considered a separate clock domain. Therefore, two flops should be used to sync the input for CDC (Clock Domain Crossing). More about [CDC here](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2008Boston_CDC.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have/want two independent inputs, you'll need to use a SR latch to store enable state. Since you're using an asynchronous latch, you won't need to debounce the buttons.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHPnVL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This makes more sense... What's the triangle on bottom?

Comment: @Amorphous: That would be your ground connection.

Comment: Hmmm.... Why would you ground your buttons?

Comment: @Amorphous: 1) So that the inputs don't float. 2) So that you can detect the transition to V+ when they're pressed.

Answer (score 0):

To use the D-FlipFlop as a toggle switch, you need to convert it to work as T-FlipFlop. To do the conversion, connect the Q~ (pin 6) to the D input (pin 2). Change the switch S2 from D to CP (pin 3). That should turn the counter on/off in the present configuration.

Comment: This doesn't work in practice. The switch contacts will "bounce" when pressed or released, giving you many edges on the clock and causing the FF to end up in a random state.